# Como fazer um script executar apenas uma vez?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou usando Asp.net MVC

No meu layout eu tenho uma div de menu

e tenho a div de container aonde está meu `@RenderBody()`

E lá embaixo tenho um script que rendeniza meu menu:

```
 $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $(".Menu").each(function (index, item) {
            var url = $(item).data("url");
            if (url && url.length > 0) {
                $(item).load(url);
            }
        });
    });
```

Porém ao clicar em outras páginas, ele está sempre chamando esse script

Pensei que por usar `@RenderBody` ele apenas desse um "Refresh" apenas na div que ele está

Comment: @RenderBody é equivalente ao include do PHP. Apenas é uma forma de reutilizar trechos de código. Para atualizar apenas uma div específica seria necessário o uso de Ajax

Answer (score 1):

@Rod o script que fica na layout é executado em todas paginas que usar a layout, para fazer isso singularmente experimente colocar o script dentro da View.

Ficaria assim na view:

```
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
// Aqui dentro seu codigo
</script>
}
```

**Atualizado:**
Você também pode montar um helper para chamar o menu em todas paginas
.Crie um arquivo MenuHelper.cshtml e declare:

```
@helper NomeDoMetodo(){
 // Código cshtml...
}
```

Depois na layout coloque:

```
 @RenderSection("MenuHelper", false)
```

E por fim basta chamar ele na View:

```
@section Menu{
    @MenuHelper.NomeDoMetodo()
}
```

Comment: Como é para montar o menu, fazendo assim ele vai montar toda vez que chamar uma view, continuará fazendo a mesma coisa, =/